# Trying to execute the given vb code but it's not working for some characters like "!", "~"

Tags: excel, vba

Please look as it is doing good with % , @ signs but not with ~ or ! will have to include more special characters.

All the code is running fine but not removing them please help and thanks for your help in advance.

```
Private Sub NewOrdersData()

Dim fndList As Variant
Dim x As Long

i = 0
n = 2

fndList = Array("!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "~")

Worksheets("UploadData").Cells.ClearContents
Sheets("ProcessedData").Activate  'data to be entered
u = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns(1), ">0")

    For i = 2 To u ' Till End of Record Count

    If Cells(i, 16) = "Upload" Then
    Sheets("UploadData").Cells(1, 1) = Cells(1, 2)
    Sheets("UploadData").Cells(1, 2) = Cells(1, 3)
    Sheets("UploadData").Cells(1, 3) = Cells(1, 4)
    Sheets("UploadData").Cells(1, 4) = Cells(1, 5)
    Sheets("UploadData").Cells(1, 5) = Cells(1, 6)
    Sheets("UploadData").Cells(1, 6) = Cells(1, 7)
    Sheets("UploadData").Cells(1, 7) = Cells(1, 8)
    Sheets("UploadData").Cells(1, 8) = Cells(1, 9)
    Sheets("UploadData").Cells(1, 9) = Cells(1, 10)
    Sheets("UploadData").Cells(1, 10) = Cells(1, 11)
    Sheets("UploadData").Cells(1, 11) = Cells(1, 12)
    Sheets("UploadData").Cells(1, 12) = Cells(1, 13)
    Sheets("UploadData").Cells(1, 13) = Cells(1, 14)
    Sheets("UploadData").Cells(n, 1) = Cells(i, 2)
    Sheets("UploadData").Cells(n, 2) = Cells(i, 3)
    Sheets("UploadData").Cells(n, 3) = Cells(i, 4)
    Sheets("UploadData").Cells(n, 4) = Cells(i, 5)
    Sheets("UploadData").Cells(n, 5) = Cells(i, 6)
    Sheets("UploadData").Cells(n, 6) = Cells(i, 7)
    Sheets("UploadData").Cells(n, 7) = Cells(i, 8)
    Sheets("UploadData").Cells(n, 8) = Cells(i, 9)
    Sheets("UploadData").Cells(n, 9) = Cells(i, 10)
    Sheets("UploadData").Cells(n, 10) = Cells(i, 11)
    Sheets("UploadData").Cells(n, 11) = Cells(i, 12)
    Sheets("UploadData").Cells(n, 12) = Cells(i, 13)
    Sheets("UploadData").Cells(n, 13) = Cells(i, 14)

    n = n + 1
    End If

    Next
For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
    Worksheets("UploadData").Cells.Replace _
What:=fndList(x), Replacement:="" ', _
    Next x

   Sheets("UploadData").Activate
           MsgBox "Complete"
End Sub
```

Comment: Try adding `Sheets("ProcessedData").` infront of all your `Cells`. Or use `with`.

Comment: Problem is not in Sheets("ProcessedData") but in UploadData it seems that the problem is in characters

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
 What:=fndList(x)
```

To:

```
What:="~" & fndList(x)
```

The `~` tells excel to look for the specific character and not use its wildcard attribute.

So yes the final string would be `"~~"`. But this will then look for the `~` and replace it.

It works also with regular characters so you do not need to change it for those that already work.  Just put it in front of everything.

I cleaned up your code a little also:

```
Private Sub NewOrdersData()

Dim fndList() As Variant
Dim x As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim u As Long, i As Long
n = 2

fndList = Array("!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "~")
With Worksheets("UploadData")
    .Cells.ClearContents
    Set ws = Sheets("ProcessedData")  'data to be entered
    u = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To u ' Till End of Record Count

        If ws.Cells(i, 16) = "Upload" Then
            .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 13)).Value = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 2), ws.Cells(1, 14)).Value
            .Range(.Cells(n, 1), .Cells(n, 13)).Value = ws.Range(ws.Cells(i, 2), ws.Cells(i, 14)).Value
            n = n + 1
        End If

    Next i
    For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
        .Cells.Replace "~" & fndList(x), ""
    Next x
    .Activate
End With

MsgBox "Complete"

End Sub
```

---

**EDIT:**

To show that the loop works I use this part of the code:

```
Sub frii()
fndList = Array("!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "~")

    For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
        Selection.Replace What:="~" & fndList(x), Replacement:=""
    Next x

End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: I tried below but it stopped it for working for others as well like %, please suggest.

For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
        Worksheets("UploadData").Cells.Replace _
 What:="!" & fndList(x), Replacement:="" ', _
'SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
        Next x

Comment: Just to mention that these characters are not in same cell

Comment: See edit the loop doing the replace works for me no problem. @SK See edit I redid your code a little.

Comment: Hello @scott it removed all the data from sheet :(

Comment: @SK Do we have the sheets backwards?  Which sheet has the data and which sheet will received the data.

Comment: @SK you mean `Worksheets("UploadData").Cells.ClearContents`??

Comment: @ScottCraner Uploaddata sheet will pull the data from processeddata sheets as processeddata is having the data

Comment: Put a break on the `For x ...` line and make sure the data is being transferred correctly. @SK

Comment: @findwindow by that before proceeding we remove all the existing data in Worksheets("UploadData").

Comment: @ScottCraner "Put a break on the For x ... line and " didn't get it please tell me what type of break and where ?

Comment: @SK comment out everything after `next i` and see if it runs as expected.

Comment: Put your cursor on that line then hit F9.  It will highlight the line red.  Then run the sub.  It will stop at that line after doing everything up to that line.

Comment: Whats not working?  Please be more specific, as this is something I do in my free time between my real work.

Comment: @ScottCraner Sorry for the inconvinience .

I think found the problem I did this 

With Worksheets("UploadData")
    .Cells.ClearContents
    Set ws = Sheets("ProcessedData")  'data to be entered
    u = 22
and it bring back the data, 

1. the formula in code for u = "WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns(1), ">0")" is to pick upto that row only which has numbers not text.

2.  as it is "~" only in code below 
For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
       .Cells.Replace "~" & fndList(x) so it removed it but not "!" or "?" signs Please help.

Comment: @SK don't know what to say.  It works for me (See Edit).  There must be something with your data.